# Distinguishing which value is obtained from COALESCE by concatenating the value to a different prefix

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT COALESCE(grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id,wells.id) as the_id,  string_agg(wells.name,', ') as well_name, sum(gas_cd) as gas_cd, date 
FROM productions
INNER JOIN completions on completions.id = productions.completion_id 
INNER JOIN wellbores on wellbores.id = completions.wellbore_id 
INNER JOIN wells on wells.id = wellbores.well_id 
INNER JOIN fields on fields.id = wells.field_id 
INNER JOIN clusters on clusters.id = fields.cluster_id
     
     
LEFT JOIN grouped_wells on grouped_wells.wells_id = wells.id
LEFT JOIN groupforecasting on groupforecasting.id = grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id and groupforecasting.workspace_id = 3
     
     
GROUP BY the_id, productions.date
ORDER BY the_id, productions.date
```

In the above SQL, I am grouping by `the_id` that results from `COALESCE`. I want to avoid grouping `grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id` of equal value to `wells.id`.
One possible way is to add a prefix depending on which of the two value I got from `COALESCE`, either add "group_" or "well_".

How to add this conditional prefix to `the_id`?

If `grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id` is Null then concatenate "well_" to the result of `COALESCE`.
Else concatenate "group_" to the result of `COALESCE`.

Comment: Hi Sami, the question seems to be interesting but I'm not sure I'm following you. Can you please provide us with some test data and expected results?

Comment: you can use case when in your select, maybe :case when grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id is NULL then concat_ws('well_', COALESCE(grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id,wells.id)) 
else concat_ws('group_', COALESCE(grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id,wells.id)) 
end as the_id

Comment: Thank you @FatFreddy. That works with little bit modifications `case when grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id is NULL then concat('well_', wells.id) else concat('group_', grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id) end as the_id`. You can put it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nearly had the solution in your

> If grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id is Null then concatenate "well_"
> to the result of COALESCE. Else concatenate "group_" to the result of
> COALESCE.

In postgres you can use the case when syntax:

```
case when ... then ...
else ... 
end as the_id
```

completing it in your select (and your comment):

```
    SELECT 
    case when grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id is NULL then concat('well_', wells.id)
         else 
    concat('group_', grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id) 
    end as the_id,
    string_agg(wells.name,', ') as well_name,
    sum(gas_cd) as gas_cd, date 
        FROM productions
        INNER JOIN completions on completions.id = productions.completion_id 
        INNER JOIN wellbores on wellbores.id = completions.wellbore_id 
        INNER JOIN wells on wells.id = wellbores.well_id 
        INNER JOIN fields on fields.id = wells.field_id 
        INNER JOIN clusters on clusters.id = fields.cluster_id
             
             
        LEFT JOIN grouped_wells on grouped_wells.wells_id = wells.id
        LEFT JOIN groupforecasting on groupforecasting.id = grouped_wells.groupforecasting_id and groupforecasting.workspace_id = 3
             
             
        GROUP BY the_id, productions.date
        ORDER BY the_id, productions.date
```